# Configuring https listener in AWS Elastic Beanstalk not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Nodejs site works fine on http, though I am not attempting to set up https. I have a wildcard certificate that I was able to successfully upload to the Amazon Certificate Manager. I have set up inbound and outbound settings for the security group as follows:

[image]

I also have the application's load balancer set with the following configuration:

[image]

However, when I attempt to access the site over https, I can't seem to connect to it.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you added the certificate to the ./ebextentions ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: option_settings:
      aws:elb:listener:443:
        SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:eu-west-1:*******:certificate/*******-****-***-****-********
        ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
        InstancePort: 80

Comment: file like this?

Comment: Yes, like this:

option_settings:
     aws:elb:listener:443
        SSLCertificateId:  <my cert id>
        ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
        InstancePort: 80